# Confused about pointers and structures

Tags: c, project

I'm trying to compare a string stored in a structure. I'm using scanf to input a string and I need to search for the string in the structure. Here is the code I have:

```
int printing_airports(int all_routes_size,int all_airports_size){

  int i,position;
  char airport;
  printf("Enter airport code:  ");
  scanf("%s", airport);

  for(i=0;i<all_airports_size;i++){
    if(strcmp(airport,all_airports_divid[i].code) == 0){
      position = i;
    }
  }
  printf("%s",all_airports_divid[position].code);
}
```

This is how I declared my structures

```
struct all_routes{
  int id;
  char departure_code[4];
  char arrival_code[4];
};
struct all_routes all_routes_divid[500];
```

This is the error I'm getting when I tried to compile

```
y:~/enee150/project2: compile
functions.c: In function 'printing_airports':
functions.c:370:15: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
functions.c:373:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/iso/string_iso.h:64:12: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Comment: There is no member with the name `code`. It is either `departure_code` or `arrival_code`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare `airport` as a `char`

```
char airport;
```

but use it as a string. Declare it `char airport[100];` or so.

```
printf("Enter airport code:  ");
scanf("%s", airport);
```

`scanf` requires a pointer to the variable the result shall be stored in as argument. When declared as `char`, `airport` is passed as an `int` to `scanf`, that is why the first message mentions `int`. The argument is dereferenced (unary `*`) to find the location where to store the scan result.

```
for(i=0;i<all_airports_size;i++){
  if(strcmp(airport,all_airports_divid[i].code) == 0){
```

`strcmp` requires a pointer (to a 0-terminated string) as argument. If passed an integral type like `char`, without explicit cast, the compiler warns about that (because 99.99+% of the time it's wrong to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a `char` to scanf, you need to pass it a `char *`; that is, a pointer to a place in memory where it can write the string that it finds.

To do this, instead of declaring `airport` as a single `char`, you need to declare it as an array; say, `char[20]`. This would not be suitable for a real application, because if the string was greater than 20 characters it would introduce a buffer overflow vulnerability, but it should be good enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
char airport;
```

Are you only expecting one char?

I think what you want is a char* hence that last line in the error.

Using char[42] would also work.

Or you could actually allocate some characters, but that doesn't seem to fit with this assignment.

Comment: oops looks like I was beat, +1

Answer (score 0):

char airport; // This must be a char* or char[] to hold the code
  printf("Enter airport code:  ");
  scanf("%s", airport); // scanf expects address of the string, while airport is a char

for(i=0;i

Moreover, there is no field by the name of code in the declared struct